# Weird behavior when mixing the tikz "let" and "plot" operation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, calc

Can anyone explain to me why the output of the following code changes when I remove   `+\x1` ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\f,blue] 
    let 
        \p1 = (0,0)
    in
        plot ({\f+\x1},{\f*\f});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In my understanding, `\x1`should contain the first coordinate of `\p1`, which is zero, so adding it should have no effect on the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing too weird going on. `\x1` has the value `0pt` in your example. Let us try

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\f,blue] 
    let 
        \p1 = (0,0)
    in 
        plot ({\f+0pt},{\f*\f});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and compare it to

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\f,blue] 
    let 
        \p1 = (0,0)
    in 
        plot ({\f*1cm+\x1},{\f*\f});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which has the result which you may have expected. The issue is that, since you add a number to something that carries the units `pt`, Ti*k*Z tries to make sense of it by assuming that everything carries these units *unless* you say otherwise.

So if you have a nontrivial `x` component you may do

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\f,blue] 
    let 
        \p1 = (0.5,0),\n1={\x1/1pt}
    in 
        plot ({\f*1cm+\n1},{\f*\f});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me finally remark that there are *really* weird things

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\f,blue] 
  let \p1 = (0.1,0),\n1={(\x1/1pt)*1cm} 
  in \pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\n1}} 
  plot ({\f+\n1},{\f*\f});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naively one might expect that this yields the same result as the one above, but it does not. However, Ti*k*Z still wants to take everything in `pt`, and the conversion multiplies the x coordinate by another factor as can be seen from the fact that the output from the `\typeout` is `2.84544pt,80.96068pt`, i.e. there is another multiplication by `28.4544`, the ratio between `cm` and `pt`.

> **Bottom-line**: If you mix units, make sure to append the desired units everywhere if they do not happen to be `pt`, which is what Ti*k*Z uses internally.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! – But according to that logic, shouldn't `({\f+\x1*1cm/1pt},{\f*\f})` also recover the original result? That somehow doesn't happen (and in my original example, the `\x1` enters in the exponent, so I really need to get the `\x1' into the standard unit...)

Comment: @ItsmeMimi On my machine `{\f*1cm+\x1*1cm/1pt}` yields the second output, i.e. the wide parabola. If you  do ``{\f+\x1*1cm/1pt}`, you get the narrow parabola. IMHO this is all consistent with my explanation. All you would have to do is to multiply in your expression `\f` by `1cm`. It is, however, true that you can get *really* weird effects if you overdo it with these conversions, try e.g. `\draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\f,blue] 
    let 
        \p1 = (0.1,0),\n1={(\x1/1pt)*1cm}
    in 
        plot ({\f+\n1},{\f*\f});`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `\x1*1cm/1pt` however carry the unit `cm`, and therefore TikZ should assume that everything is in the cm unit? – I will mark your answer as correct, because you definitely solved the original question. Unfortunately, my actual plot is more like your comment example, and I just can't get rid of the weird behavior there. :( 
Do you understand why it seems to shift the plot by 3 horizontally, rather than 0.1? The `\f*1cm` trick recovers the wide parabola, but the shift is still way too big... rounding errors??

Comment: @ItsmeMimi I expanded the answer a bit. The upshot is that, yes, Ti*k*Z seems to overdo it a bit with adding `pt` wherever it is not sure. (Luckily you are careful enough to call the plot variable `\f` rather than `\x` because this is another source of confusion. In plots, I usually use the `\n1=....` syntax to make use of coordinates that are read out from `calc` elements, but I agree that here this is not necessary.)